# MySQL equivalent of mysql_num_rows. Which is better?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm in the process of turning all of mysql related stuff in PHP into PDO format. That being said, I need to ask something.

I know that instead of using mysql_num_rows() to find out the number of rows returned, a good alternative is

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table"
```

Well, with PDO, is it better to do:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count($results);
```

OR

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use the `SELECT`ed data? Because in that case the second one is better. The first one doesn't even return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is "a good alternative". It is something completely different.

```
    SELECT data FROM table
```

fetches data, that you can use. You can then use `mysql_num_rows()` (or `rowCount()` in the PDO case) to get the number of records (for rendering, pagination or whatever).

If you only want the number of records (and not the actual data), you should use

```
    SELECT COUNT(data) FROM table
```

as you are only selecting the **number** of records (to be precise, you are counting non-NULL values of `data`, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` to get all records).

If you would be using the latter in combination with the former to get both, you could get into trouble when the number of records change between the two queries.

Comment: It's PHP. There are **plenty** of codes all over the Net suggesting `SELECT *` / `num_rows` to get the count. From this point of view `SELECT COUNT(*)` is indeed better alternative ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense to me.
As you already knows that to ask a database only for a **number** of rows is way better than asking for **all the rows** themselves and then count them out - why do you think if it would be otherwise if you're using just different db driver?

To answer your question literally: `SELECT COUNT(*)` is not a "good alternative" but the **only** proper method of counting rows, no matter what particular API were used to send the query to the database.

However, as it was pointed out in comments - if you are already selecting rows, and want to know number of rows returned - it would be quite contrary: to run an extra query to get the count would make no sense and whatever API function to get the row count of the result set would be the only right way.
But anyway, these matters are irrelevant to migration from one API to another.

**Update**
Aha, looks like I got to the root of your confusion!
Looks like you were mistaken by the old API which share it's name with database server - mysql.
As a matter of fact, it's different matters - MySQL RDBMS is a database server while mysql extension in PHP is just an API (a set of functions) to access that server.
And PDO is not a database server, but rather another API. So, there is **no change** in your queries, but only in functions you're using to send them to DB. Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess he wants to query some data, and then find out how much he actually got (to do correct rendering, or whatever). Without having to query twice.

Comment: Well, sometimes all the info I need to know can be determined by the number of rows. With regular mysql functions in php, I would use mysql_num_rows() when I needed to actually select columns and use the number of rows. However, when I just need to number of rows returned, I would just use SELECT COUNT(*). PDO is fairly new to me.

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT COUNT` without a `GROUP BY` will always only return 1 row with 1 field, being the total amount of rows that match your `COUNT` condition, which is in this case everything. So doing a PHP `count()` on that result will always return `1`, since there is just 1 element in the `$results` array. So option 2 of these two is the only valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be this

```
$nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from table')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $nRows;
```

**Edit**: Removed count.

Comment: Wouldn't this **always** return "1", as `count` would always be existant (but just have a different value?)